# strange crash on fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

So, this is my very small code which I was about to start but FOR AN UNKNOWN reason it crashes on `scanf`. I checked with `printf` and that's the place where it crashes. I've tried a lot of things and I can avoid this problem but I just want to know what's wrong if you could please tell me.

For example this can be datafile:

```
19/03/2017 Good
17/03/2017 Terrible
18/03/2017 Good
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DATA_FILE "Database.txt"
#define MAX_USERS 50

typedef struct data {
    char date;
    char feeling;
} data;

int ReadData(data *p1, FILE *fp);

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen(DATA_FILE, "r");
    data *p1;
    p1 = (struct data*)malloc(MAX_USERS * sizeof(struct data));
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Database is empty!");
        exit(1);
    }
    ReadData(p1, fp);
}

int ReadData(data *p1, FILE *fp) {
    int i = 0;
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s", (p1 + i)->date, (p1 + i)->feeling);
        printf("%s %s", &(p1 + i)-> date, &(p1 + i)-> feeling);
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: The struct members `date` and `feeling` are not the strings required by the `%s` format given to `fscanf`. They are single characters, please enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: You should change the question, there is no instance of scanf in this code, so it makes it really confusing, I just read through all this code looking for scanf, but there's only fscanf, which does something totally different than scanf, is that what you mean?

Comment: Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @TrevorHart  My fault, sorry and edited.

Comment: @WeatherVane they are no single characters, how can they be

Comment: `char date;` is a single `char`. You'll need something like `char date[20];` to use the format spec `%s`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks man, how could I miss it. Sorry and thank you for your time.

Comment: @Quto: if your question was answered, you might accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mismatch between how you define `date` and `feeling` in your `struct` type:

```
typedef struct data
{
    char date;
    char feeling;
}data;
```

and how you're treating them in the `scanf` call:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %s", (p1+i)->date, (p1+i)->feeling);
```

Remember that `%s` expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *`, and to point to the first element of an *array* of `char`, not a single char.  You've declared `date` and `feeling` to be single `char`s.  And, `(p1+i)->date` does not evaluate to the *address* of the `date` member within the instance.

For this to work as you are intending it to, both `date` and `feeling` need to be declared as either *arrays* of `char`:

```
typedef struct data
{
    char date[MAX_DATE_LENGTH+1];        // where MAX_DATE_LENGTH and MAX_FEELING_LENGTH
    char feeling[MAX_FEELING_LENGTH+1];  // are constant integral expressions; +1 to account
}data;                                   // for string terminator
```

*or*, you need to define `date` and `feeling` as pointers to `char` and allocate memory for them later:

```
typedef struct data
{
    char *date;
    char *feeling;
}data;
...
p1[i]->date = malloc( MAX_DATE_LENGTH + 1 );
p1[i]->feeling = malloc( MAX_FEELING_LENGTH + 1 );
```

*Now*, your `scanf` call will work with one minor tweak:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %s", p1[i].date, p1[i].feeling);
```

`(p1 + i)->date` works, but I think using regular subscript notation is easier to read and follow.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should define the `date` and `feeling` members of structure `data` as arrays of characters instead of single `char` types.  For example:

  ```
  typedef struct data {
      char date[20];
      char feeling[40];
  } data;
  ```
- Using the pointer syntax `(p1 + i) -> date` is considered much less readable than the equivalent array syntax: `p1[i].date`.
- The arguments to `fscanf` are incorrect: you must pass the address of a character array for format `%s`.  You pass the **value** of the members instead of their addresses, a very probable cause for the crash. Passing the address of single `char` members would be incorrect a single `char` cannot hold a string.  With the updated structure definition, you should write:

  ```
  fscanf(fp, "%19s %39s", p1[i].date, p1[i].feeling);
  ```

  `p1[i].date` is now an array, so passing it as an argument actually passes the address of it first element.

  Specifying a width of `19` tells `fscanf()` to not store more than `19` characters before the null terminator into the destination array.
- `while(!feof(fp))` is always the wrong way to test for end of file.  Instead check that `fscanf()` succeeds at converting 2 strings:

  ```
  while (fscanf(fp, "%19s %19s", p1[i].date, p1[i].feeling) == 2) { ...
  ```
- You pass the address of single `char` values to `printf` for the `%s` specifier. This is incorrect.  With the updated structure definition, use this:

  ```
  printf("%s %s", p1[i].date, p1[i].feeling);
  ```
- You should stop reading the file when you have converted `MAX_USERS` entries.
- You should check for memory allocation failure
- You should free the memory block
- You should close the file
- Parsing the date as a single word is probably OK, but the feeling should allow multiple words, as in `Very bad` and `So so`. Use format `%[^\n]` for that.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DATA_FILE "Database.txt"
#define MAX_USERS 50

typedef struct data {
    char date[20];
    char feeling[40];
} data;

int ReadData(data *p1, FILE *fp);

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    data *p1;
    int data_count;  /* number of records read */

    fp = fopen(DATA_FILE, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Database not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    p1 = malloc(MAX_USERS * sizeof(struct data));
    if (p1 == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory\n");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }
    data_count = ReadData(p1, fp);

    /* Do something with the data */

    free(p1);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int ReadData(data *p1, FILE *fp) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_USERS; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%19s %39[^\n]", p1[i].date, p1[i].feeling) != 4)
            break;
        printf("%s %s", p1[i].date, p1[i].feeling);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `date` and `feeling` fields in your database are strings. You are reading them as strings by specifying `%s` in the `fscanf` format. But you are trying to store them in a memory location of just 1 byte length.

Replace

```
typedef struct data
{
    char date;
    char feeling;
}data;
```

with

```
typedef struct data
{
    char date[11];
    char feeling[20];
}data;
```

Answer (score 0):

char date; is a single char. You'll need something like char date[20]; to use the format spec %s.